# How do you debug ASP.NET startup issues using the Development Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have created a new ASP.NET MVC project using the MVC Project Template.  According to the book I am reading the ASP.NET MVC book I am reading (Pro ASP.NET MVC framework by APRESS) the application is supposed to just run out of the box using the Visual Studio Development Server.

It DOES compile and run but IE returns a page load error...specifically the following error:

```
This problem can be caused by a variety of issues, including: 

•Internet connectivity has been lost.
•The website is temporarily unavailable.
•The Domain Name Server (DNS) is not reachable.
•The Domain Name Server (DNS) does not have a listing for the website's domain.
•There might be a typing error in the address.
•If this is an HTTPS (secure) address, click Tools, click Internet Options, click Advanced, and check to be sure the SSL and TLS protocols are enabled under the security section.
```

I am running Visual Studio 8 on Windows 7 RC1.  I do have IIS installed and running on my machine.

I would prefer getting this to work using the VS Development Server but I have no idea why the page doesn't load.

**EDIT**
Even with firewall turned off...same problem. I use Windows Firewall.
I am running Visual STudio AS AN Administrator...fyi.

Seth

Comment: That error means that IE can not connect to the web server. Do you see the Visual Studio Dev Server icon in the taskbar?

Comment: Yes...the icon is there and referencing a port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that I had a strange entry in my hosts file.  It was ::1.  Not sure what that was...but since it was after the 127.0.0.1 entry it was flubbing things up.

I commented out that line and all is well.

DETAILS...for future similar problem.

I opened c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc.  THere is a file there called hosts (no file extension.)  Save it to your desktop (Vista and Win 7 will not allow you to simply edit and save this file.).  Edit it as necessary.  Copy and replace the original in the above path.

Seth

Comment: I had the same issue, apparently some windows update alters the hosts file and mucks up the entry for localhost.  If you want to test to see if it's this replace the "localhost" part of the url for "127.0.0.1", it this works then its the hosts file problem

Comment: ::1 is the IP address for the IPv6 loopback address.

Answer (score 1):

Which port is the development server running on?  If it is a port that happens to be used or blocked (firewall) by another program, it could be causing a conflict.  You can try changing the port that the development server uses in the project properties to see if that solves anything.  You should also disable your firewall to confirm that it isn't causing any issues.

Comment: Even with firewall turned off...same problem.